# pytest/unittest: mock.patch function from module?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, python-unittest

Given a folder structure like such:

```
dags/
  **/
    code.py
tests/
  dags/
    **/
      test_code.py
  conftest.py
```

Where dags serves as the root of the src files, with 'dags/a/b/c.py' imported as 'a.b.c'.

I want to test the following function in code.py:

```py
from dag_common.connections import get_conn
from utils.database import dbtypes

def select_records(
    conn_id: str,
    sql: str,
    bindings,
):
    conn: dbtypes.Connection = get_conn(conn_id)
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(
            sql, bindings
        )
        records = cursor.fetchall()
    return records
```

But I am faced with the issue that I fail to find a way to patch the `get_conn` from `dag_common.connections`. I attempted the following:

### (1) Globally in conftest.py

```
import os
import sys

# adds dags to sys.path for tests/*.py files to be able to import them
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", "dags"))

{{fixtures}}
```

Where I have tested the following replacements for `{{fixtures}}`:

**(1.a) - default**

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def mock_get_conn():
    with mock.patch("dag_common.connections.get_conn") as mock_getter:
        yield mock_getter
```

**(1.b) - prefixing path with dags**

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def mock_get_conn():
    with mock.patch("dags.dag_common.connections.get_conn") as mock_getter:
        yield mock_getter
```

**(1.c) - 1.a, with scope="session"**

**(1.d) - 1.b, with scope="session"**

**(1.e) - object patching the module itself**

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def mock_get_conn():
    import dags.dag_common.connections
    mock_getter = mock.MagicMock()
    with mock.patch.object(dags.dag_common.connections, 'get_conn', mock_getter):
        yield mock_getter
```

**(1.f) - 1.a, but using pytest-mock fixture**

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def mock_get_conn(mocker):
    with mocker.patch("dag_common.connections.get_conn") as mock_getter:
        yield mock_getter
```

(1.g) - 1.b, but using pytest-mock fixture

(1.h) - 1.a, but using pytest's monkeypatch

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="function")
def mock_get_conn(mocker, monkeypatch):
    import dags.dag_common.connections
    mock_getter = mocker.MagicMock()
    monkeypatch.setattr(dags.dag_common.connections, 'get_conn', mock_getter)
    yield mock_getter
```

### (2) Locally applying mock.patch in the test/as a decorator

**(2.a) - decorator @mock.patch("dag_common.connections.get_conn")**

```py
    @mock.patch("dag_common.connections.get_conn")
    def test_executes_sql_with_default_bindings(mock_getter, mock_context):
        # arrange
        sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
        records = [RealDictRow(col1=1), RealDictRow(col1=2)]
        mock_conn = mock_getter.return_value
        mock_cursor = mock_conn.cursor.return_value
        mock_cursor.execute.return_value = records
        # act
        select_records(conn_id="orca", sql=sql, ) # ...
        # assert
        mock_cursor.execute.assert_called_once_with(
            sql, # ...
        )
```

**(2.b) - (2.a) but with "dags." prefix**

**(2.c) - context manager**

```py
    def test_executes_sql_with_default_bindings(mock_context):
        # arrange
        sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
        records = [RealDictRow(col1=1), RealDictRow(col1=2)]
        with mock.patch("dag_common.connections.get_conn") as mock_getter:
            mock_conn = mock_getter.return_value
            mock_cursor = mock_conn.cursor.return_value
            mock_cursor.execute.return_value = records
            # act
            select_records(conn_id="orca", sql=sql, ) # ...
            # assert
            mock_cursor.execute.assert_called_once_with(
                sql, # ...
            )
```

**(2.d) - (2.c) but with "dags." prefix**

---

### Conclusion

But alas, no matter what solution I pick, the function-to-be-mocked still gets called.
I made sure to attempt each solution separatedly from each other, and to kill/clear/restart my pytest-watch process in between attempts.

I feel like this may be related to me meddling with sys.path in conftest.py, because outside of this I feel like I have exhausted all possibilities.

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Would it be possible to refactor the code so that instead of passing `conn_id` you directly pass the result of `get_conn(conn_id)`? This way you just construct a mock connection outside of the method and pass it to the method under test.

Comment: Try patching `"a.b.c.code.get_conn"`

Comment: @flakes, thanks for your answer! I accepted Jarek Potiuk's answer, which suggest the same as you suggest.

Comment: @MarcelloRomani That's an option I considered, but I'd rather stay it that way. As such, the knowledge of the connection objects is scoped to the function rather than across multiple modules :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yeah. I also fought with this initially when I learned patching and mocking and know how frustrating it is as you seem to be doing everything right, but it does not work. I sympathise with you!

This is actually how mocking of imported stuff works, and once you realise it, it actually makes sense.

The problem is that import works in the way that it makes the imported module available in the context of where your import is.

Lets' assume your `code.py` module is in 'my_package' folder. Your code is available then as `my_package.code`. And once you use `from dag_common.connections import get_conn` in `code` module  - the imported `get_conn` becomes available as .... `my_package.code.get_conn`

And in this case you need to patch `my_package.code.get_conn` not the original package you imported get_conn from.

Once you realise this, patching becomes much easier.

Comment:   Thank you so much for this Jarek! I stumbled across similar answers on other SO threads, but none explained this in a way that help me understand what you said now. This solves my issue entirely! And thanks for coming over from apache/airflow! ❤

Comment: Glad I could help. I still remember the same frustration and enlightenment moment when I understood why it is this way! I wish it was more "obviously" explained somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Since the example you are showcasing is relevant to Apache Airflow, another way you can actually use in order to mock Airflow Connections and/or Variables is by mocking the corresponding environment variables.

---

For example,

```
from unittest import mock

import pytest
from airflow.models.connection import Connection


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='function')
def mock_my_conn():
    conn = Connection(conn_type='', login='', host='')
    yield conn.get_uri()


def test_my_dag(mock_my_conn):
    with mock.patch.dict('os.environ', AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_CONN=mock_my_conn):
        ...
```

---

Or if you want to mock multiple connections in a single test case:

```
def test_my_dag(mock_my_conn):
    with mock.patch.dict(
        'os.environ', {
            'AIRFLOW_CONN_MY_CONN': mock_my_conn,
            'AIRFLOW_CONN_ANOTHER_CONN': mock_my_conn,
        }
    ):
        ...
```